# Can´t change ChromeType under Sharepoint User

Tags: web-part, xml, wiki

I programmatically added a WebPart to a ASPX - site with chrometype "None". With a SharePoint Administrator the Code is working. But with a SharePoint user, the chrometype will not be changed.

The Code:

```
wikiPage.CheckOut();
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager wpmgr = wikiPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
WebPart WP = new CustomWebParts.Comment.Comment();

WP.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;

wpmgr.AddWebPart(WP, "ZoneTemplate", 1);
wpmgr.SaveChanges(WP);

wikiPage.CheckIn(string.Empty, SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
```

Also i tried to add a XML property in the ".webpart" file but nothing happens.

```
<property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that where you do this in the web part life-cycle.

If you do it as part of the Render method it will be too late - the chrome has already been drawn by then.

On the other end of the scale if you do it to early then your setting will be overridden when SharePoint applies the settings from the toolpart.

Look at doing it in something like the `OnPreRender` event.

Comment: I add a OnPreRenter Event in the comment webpart and it works. Thanks a lot